# Jquery inserting images crashes my form

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation I have such problem: I insert images, when input valid or not. When they are inserting one image is showing fully, but make margin and crash my div, and second - with same css attributes - showing partly and doesn't crash anything.

I'm using Rails and my form is on Bootstrap modal.

Here is screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbirM.png

Here is css :

```
label.error {
color:transparent;
display: inline;  
background: url('not_valid.png') no-repeat;
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 47px;
height: 36px;
}
label.valid {
background: url('valid.png') no-repeat;
display: inline;  
padding: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
color:transparent;
width: 47px;
height: 36px;
}
input{
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(98,141, 40, 0.5);
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px rgba(98,141, 40, .2);
}
input.valid{
    border: 1px solid rgb(98,141, 40);
    font-size: 14px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(98,141, 40, 0.2);    
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>JCheck</title>
    <link href="application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jcheck.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="EoQ2xPXGeDJpKsf22dPZcFQDUfj8cAfV8owQ493TkGU=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function() { var validator = jQuery('#new_user').jcheck({'field_prefix': 'user'}); validator.validates('email', {'presence': {'if': 'email_required?'}, 'format': {'with': /\A[^@]+@([^@\.]+\.)+[^@\.]+\z/, 'allow_blank': true, 'if': 'email_changed?'}, 'presence': true}); validator.validates('password', {'presence': {'if': 'password_required?'}, 'confirmation': {'if': 'password_required?'}, 'length': {'allow_blank': true, 'minimum': 6, 'maximum': 128}}); validator.validates('name', {'presence': true}); validator.field('email').custom_label = 'Email'; validator.field('password').custom_label = 'Password'; validator.field('name').custom_label = 'Name'; }); </script>

<h2>Sign up</h2>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="sign_up" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="EoQ2xPXGeDJpKsf22dPZcFQDUfj8cAfV8owQ493TkGU=" /></div>


<div><label for="user_name">Name</label><br />
    <input id="user_name" name="user[name]" size="30" type="text" /></div>

  <div><label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>

  <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br />
    <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" size="30" type="password" /></div>

  <div><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br />
    <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" size="30" type="password" /></div>

  <div><input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign up" /></div>
</form>
  <a href="/users/sign_in">Sign in</a><br />
  <a href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

All my files:
    https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ea9k2z6vmsvg58/Pz5X0qRNDv (remove coma after "success")

When I give more padding to label.valid it is showing. I can't get why they don't behave the same ? Where is problem ?

Comment: The problem may be with your form's/textbox's total width. Can you provide the whole form's html and CSS code?

Comment: I will give you link to my files.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1ea9k2z6vmsvg58/Pz5X0qRNDv

Comment: please post the relevant code in your question and don't link to dropbox. If you remove the files there, the question is useless.

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks for iniciative.

Comment: post your answer and accept it so we know your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about default error messages. So I just remove them (because they were transparent, that was needed for my project) - only show images without text.